# Angular 6 dropdown not working in IE / Edge

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a regular Dropdown that I load from a loop in my model. Everything works fine in Chrome even model binding. However, when I go to IE/Edge I can select it but when I come back to the page my selection disappears (model binding).

I have imported all the libraries in the *polyfills.ts* file. 
Is there any other library that I am missing?

Is there a bug in Angular 6 that is related to IE/Edge support?

Why is it behaving like this?

How do I solve this problem?

Here is a sample code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="changeDetails.program" name="program" #program="ngModel" required class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let subProgram of programs">{{subProgram}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Add `ngValue` to resolve problem

Comment: @KarolTrybulec how exactly given the code that I have in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking to store the value, so something like this?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="changeDetails.program" name="program" #program="ngModel" required 
     class="form-control">
         <option *ngFor="let subProgram of programs" [value]="subProgram.value"> 
         {{subProgram}}</option>
</select>
```